# How do I sort a bar graph in descending order in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Say you had people's names and their exam scores. When you generate a bar graph with their score as y-axis and name as the x-axis, how can you make the bar graph display the people with the highest score in the left and descend all the way to the right to the people with the lowest scores?

Comment: This isn't about programming as set out in [ask].  It's more about application usage and would get a better reception on [su].

Comment: Sorry. I found similar questions in stackoverflow and assumed this would be an appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the data source. The chart will plot the data points in the order of the data source. Most likely, a horizontal bar chart will be more suitable than a vertical columns chart. The names will be easier to read.